# Emulator for Android Studio not launching due to 2 Warnings: "No gRPC protection active" and "Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported"

Tags: api, android-studio, android-emulator, grpc, virtual-device-manager

When launching the Emulator for Android Studio I get the following WARN messages:

C:\Users***myUser**\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.3\log\idea.log

WARN - Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.

WARN - Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***

Does anyone know how to fix this ? Thanks !

I do no to know what to do to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to enable virtualization in your bios for your CPU. The second warning will not stop the running of an AVD, I wouldn't worry about it.